# R error in x[tips, ]: Incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I have a table of Procrustes coordinates from shape analysis of 3D models. I abridged the dataset to the first 10 columns of coordinates; the actual data table has 213 columns of coordinates.

```
> table
                     V2           V3         V4          V5          V6         V7          V8          V9        V10         V11
ZF_1-2_MCA  -0.11729989 -0.007414411 0.04796147 -0.11369870 -0.02162879 0.04368074 -0.11078641 -0.03099347 0.03429351 -0.10957045
CM_MCA      -0.09751743  0.002636377 0.05329538 -0.09225709 -0.01366208 0.04885578 -0.08766362 -0.02705151 0.03623264 -0.08611709
McG_MCA     -0.10568420 -0.001580294 0.05121677 -0.11160321 -0.02146946 0.04529592 -0.11638602 -0.03359730 0.03200932 -0.11966146
FR-5_MCA    -0.08724930 -0.004697084 0.06544431 -0.09398249 -0.02745482 0.05295470 -0.09963358 -0.04310317 0.03419766 -0.10472636
VS_MCA      -0.08501951 -0.009980739 0.04646973 -0.08341840 -0.03356989 0.03536958 -0.08682687 -0.04914396 0.01880115 -0.09337424
p12_MCA     -0.11108448 -0.005535405 0.02829126 -0.10942936 -0.01807344 0.02311581 -0.10875525 -0.02613395 0.01434359 -0.10887946
PE_MCA      -0.08839262  0.001058080 0.05815368 -0.08645855 -0.01712989 0.05200591 -0.08750906 -0.03150924 0.04118683 -0.09082429
HGN_MCA     -0.11196640 -0.004789709 0.05680164 -0.11191664 -0.01980991 0.04895458 -0.11187914 -0.02944595 0.03732340 -0.11166266
SP-5_MCA    -0.10900994  0.000010200 0.04009365 -0.10901557 -0.01422714 0.03609224 -0.11093003 -0.02471116 0.02897352 -0.11390505
NeM_1-2_MCA -0.09786814  0.004310618 0.07448896 -0.10902664 -0.02236152 0.06831984 -0.12283099 -0.04654299 0.04958811 -0.12704721
WN-3_MCA    -0.10088474 -0.001611016 0.05684335 -0.10359814 -0.02212326 0.05120036 -0.10638614 -0.03585422 0.04040904 -0.10794333
AIJ_MCA     -0.09909852  0.000849000 0.04575036 -0.10102173 -0.01626784 0.03898051 -0.10387869 -0.02855804 0.03008275 -0.10703389
GoD_MCA     -0.09986131  0.000498000 0.04508524 -0.09756908 -0.01823467 0.04039427 -0.09674259 -0.03295781 0.03271970 -0.09712355
TN_MCA      -0.10975100 -0.005714795 0.03865324 -0.10873629 -0.01830583 0.03378409 -0.10929496 -0.02737490 0.02527304 -0.11036554
p49_MCA_1   -0.09170672 -0.004816696 0.04631250 -0.09873852 -0.02439218 0.04288983 -0.10913437 -0.03936764 0.03365113 -0.11881931
```

I'm trying to run a phylogenetic analysis on my dataset using the `Rphylip` package. The coordinates are continuous variables, so I'm trying to run `Rcontml` after inserting the table.

```
> library(Rphylip)
> table<-read.table("procrustes_D_phylip.txt", row.name=1)
```

The documentation for the package indicates that the table just needs the species' as the row names. The V# column labels are default. So it seems like the table is set up properly. But when I try to run `Rcontml`, I get the following error:

```
> Rcontml(table)
Error in x[tips, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I tried searching the forums for an error with an incorrect number of dimensions, but there's nothing specific to `x[tips, ]`. I'm relatively new to R and this package is also new to me and my PI, so I'd appreciate any insight into this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package but according to [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rphylip/versions/0.1-23/topics/Rcontml) your input needs to be _"either (a) a matrix of continuous valued traits (in columns) with rownames containing species names; or (b) a list of matrices in which each row contains the relative frequency of alleles at a locus for a species. In the latter case the rownames of each matrix in the list should contain the species names."_ The output for `read.table` is a data.frame. Have you tried converting it to a matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I didn't know about the structure of the `read.table` output. `Rcontml` seems to be reading the matrix, but I'm getting a new set of errors: `Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'touch outfile' had status 127 
2: running command '/Users/Anthony/Downloads/phylip/contml' had status 127 
3: In file(file, "r") :
  cannot open file 'outtree': No such file or directory
` Status 127 means that the command can't be found, so I'm guessing I'm missing a file from the package?

Comment: I got it to work! The `status 127` really was indicating that I was missing commands. Apparently, the .zip file that I extracted `phylip` from hitched somewhere in the process and I was missing _a lot_ of executable files. So the only problem I was having was realizing the difference between a data frame and a matrix. I wish I could upvote your comment! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I'll add it as an answer (which you can accept as the right answer), maybe someone else will benefit from the question/answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the solution over the comments here the summary:

The import of the data with `read.table` returns a `data.frame`.

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rphylip/versions/0.1-23/topics/Rcontml) for `Rcontml` the following input is allowed:

> either (a) a *matrix* of continuous valued traits (in columns) with rownames containing species names; or (b) a list of matrices in which each row contains the relative frequency of alleles at a locus for a species. In the latter case the rownames of each matrix in the list should contain the species names.

Converting the `data.frame` to a `matrix` solves the problem.